# How to get image in specified size given in parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display image in specified size given in parameter like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOQ8r.jpg?s=128&g=1 .

Suppose my `image1.jpg` is in image folder like this `http://example.com/images/image1.jpg` then if I specify the parameter like `?s=200` then image should be resized to `200x200` size and display without any other element except `<img>` tag.

I am not asking about code and example. I just need a logic or an idea. B'Coz, I am completely blank about it. Even I don't know what should I search on google. I am new in Web Application Development.

I want just same as http://lorempizza.com/ developed by [rlemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon)

Plz give some ideas about it. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Aww, you should have pinged me, I would have been more than willing to help. Glad it is sorted tho. Cheers!

Comment: @rlemon Yes, I was supposed so ping you in C# room. But, i thought I should try it my self first. If I don't get the solution then I will ask you. btw, thanks for your valuable reply. You are doing really very nice work. I am just following you at [codepen.io/rlemon](http://codepen.io/rlemon/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following function to re-size the image

```
public Image ImageResize(Image image, int width, int height)
{
     Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
     using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
     {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
     }
     return newImage as Image;
}
```

and to display the image

1- use the asp image tag

```
<asp:Image id="imageTag" runat="server"/>
```

2- save the Image to a folder by the following
Image temp=ImageResize(YourImage,200,200);

```
temp.SaveAs(MapPath("~/Images/image1.png"));
```

3- map the image url to the path

```
imageTag.ImageUrl=Server.MapPath("~/Images/image1.png");
```

another approach, is to use the ashx handler if you insist to use `<img>`, but at the end , asp:Image will be rendered as `<img>`

Edited Here

how to get the image resized using ashx

1- create a generic handler and name it ImageHandler

```
 public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var directory = @"Location of the images" // example c:\Data;
            var path = context.Request.QueryString["path"];
            var size = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["size"]);
            var image = Image.FromFile(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.png", directory, path));
            image = ImageResize(image, size, size);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(ImageToByte(image));
        }

        public Image ImageResize(Image image, int width, int height)
        {
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
            }
            return newImage as Image;
        }

        public byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                stream.Close();

                byteArray = stream.ToArray();
            }
            return byteArray;
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

2- in the aspx page, use the following

```
<img src="~/ImageHandler.ashx?path=NameOfImage&size=SizeOfImage" runat="server" />
```

hope this will help you

regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hadi Hassan. your solution is very useful when i upload the image on the webserver with specified image size. But, in my case i just want to return an image in specified height and width from the webserver without re-writing it.

Comment: then you can use ashx handler that will act as a custom render, but if you will not resize the image, and just you will render <img width=200 height=200 src='url'/>, this has performance issue!

Comment: that's what i am looking for. actually the image size can be any and I don't want to lose the original size of my image. I have found a link as you have told me that use ashx handler http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx . Can you take a look at this example is this tutorial correct for me and can you modify your answer as per my requirement. So, i can accept your answer.

Comment: check my solution please,it worked with me after testing, if this will solve your problem, please mark as answer, regards